# Фильтрация в listview

Tags: android, listview, java

привет всем.
мне нужно отфильтровать listview.
есть edittext и listview, в листвью содержится нное количество строк, пользователь начинает что-нибудь вводить в едиттекст - и сразу же начинают фильтроваться строки в листвью.
насколько я понял, нужно создать экземпляр класса адаптер, и затем уже в событии onTextChanged для моего edittext прописать примерно следующее:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);   
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

но проблема в том, что я не создаю адаптер, у меня есть класс, который расширяет адаптер.
и где-то в коде я делаю примерно следующие вещи:

```
lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,data));
```

как быть?

Comment: > я не создаю адаптер, у меня есть класс, который расширяет адаптер. и где-то в коде я делаю примерно следующие вещи:  

new MyAdapter(this,data)  - а как это назвать, как не создание адаптера 0_о

Comment: от адаптера нельзя унаследоваться, я наследуюсь от BaseAdapter, а метода getFilter() у него нет

Comment: что мешает реализовать интерфейс Filterable?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android  
  
или
можете унаследоваться от ArrayAdapter и все будет в шоколаде  
http://androidcocktail.blogspot.ru/2012/04/search-custom-listview-in-android.html    

ЗЫ: Гугл рулит ;)

Comment: тебе в EditText нужно повесить слушатель onTextChanged, а фильтровать надо данные которые наследует ListView. 
Если бы ты написал, что у тебя такое data я бы выложил полный пример.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону `AutoCompleteTextView` - там уже реализован такой функционал